# Key Error:3 while using For to plot using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyerror

I have a dataset with 10 columns, in which column 4 and 8 are the data I want to plot, and column 9 is determining the marker type.

```
mkr_dict = {'Fluoride': 'D', 'Chloride': 'P', 'Bromide': 'o', 'Iodide' : '^'}
for kind in mkr_dict:
    d = df[df.Halogen==kind]
    plt.scatter(d[3], d[7], 
                s = 20,
                c = 'red',
                marker=mkr_dict[kind])
plt.show()
```

I keep getting Key Error: 3 while executing.
Can someone give me an advice?

Comment: `df[df.Halogen==kind]` will look for a key True or False

Comment: I'm new to coding, I used the reference from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313882/scatterplot-with-different-size-marker-and-color-from-pandas-dataframe

Can you explain the difference between my code and the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the following minimal example, the code from the question may run fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(50,8)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df["Halogen"] = np.random.choice(['Fluoride','Chloride','Bromide','Iodide'], size=50)


mkr_dict = {'Fluoride': 'D', 'Chloride': 'P', 'Bromide': 'o', 'Iodide' : '^'}
for kind in mkr_dict:
    d = df[df.Halogen==kind]
    plt.scatter(d[3], d[7], 
                s = 20,
                c = 'red',
                marker=mkr_dict[kind])
plt.show()
```

However, if the columns are not numbered, but have a name instead, something like `d[3]` will fail. You would then need to select the column by its index,

```
d.iloc[:,3]
```

or by its name (in the case below, e.g. `d.D` or `d["D"]`). A version using `iloc`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(50,8)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=list("ABCDEFGH"))
df["Halogen"] = np.random.choice(['Fluoride','Chloride','Bromide','Iodide'], size=50)


mkr_dict = {'Fluoride': 'D', 'Chloride': 'P', 'Bromide': 'o', 'Iodide' : '^'}
for kind in mkr_dict:
    d = df[df.Halogen==kind]
    plt.scatter(d.iloc[:,3], d.iloc[:,7], 
                s = 20,
                c = 'red',
                marker=mkr_dict[kind])
plt.show()
```