# Getting "key error" while plotting using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do a simple plot of a data from a text file. Below is the file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
03-10-16,774.25,776.065002,769.578768,772.559998
04-10-16,776.03,778.710022,772.890015,776.429993
05-10-16,779.30,782.070007,775.650024,776.469971
06-10-16,779.00,780.479989,775.539978,776.859985
07-10-16,779.65,779.659973,770.757867,775.080017
```

Below is the python code i m trying to execute:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('financial.txt', index_col=0)
df.plot(x=df.index, y=df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
KeyError: "Index(['03-10-16', '04-10-16', '05-10-16', '06-10-16', '07-10-16'], dtype='object', name='Date') not in index"
```

I am not sure why i am getting that error? Although i have achieved what i wanted by using csv but not sure why i am getting that error. 
Checked for the same error online as well but didn't get much.I have checked this.
[Key Error:3 while using For to plot using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263070/key-error3-while-using-for-to-plot-using-matplotlib-pyplot-scatter)

Any light on the error is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification will work. You misunderstood how to use df.plot(). Please refer this page [visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html). This code below is just a basic visualization, you can change to **df.plot.box()** or **df.plot.area()** to get more advanced visualization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('financial.txt', index_col=0)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Giang!! But the above doesn't show my the dates on the x axis. How can i Do that?

Comment: Oh sorry, but which date? I see that the dates are already showed.

Comment: Sorry, its there for you, but unfortunately its not coming for me. Something wrong with the IDE i guess.

Comment: one more question, Here the labels are coming by default as the first row(header) in the file and the x and the y axes needn't be defined?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.1, pandas==0.24.1 and matplotlib==3.0.0. Hope this helps. Anyway, you can try other visualizations as i mentioned.

Comment: Yes. It comes by default, and matplotlib is clever enough to recognize the date that could be used as x axes.