# How to plot a circle for each point scatter plot while each has particular radius size

Tags: python, pca, plotly-python

I have a pandas frame with distance matrix, I use PCA to do the dim reduction. The the dataframe of this distance matrix has label for each point, and size.

How can I make each scattered point become a circle with a size dependent on the size from the dataframe

`````
````
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(dist)
mds5 = pca.components_

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(x = mds5[0],
       y = mds5[1],
       mode = 'markers+text',
       marker= dict(size = 8,
             color= 'blue'
            ),
text= dist.columns.values,
textposition='top right')
````
`````

I need to have the scatter plot looks something like this example, however, when I add the size for each point in related answers, I cant get the circles to overlap, and when they do, I can zoom in, then they dont overlap anymore

sounds strange, but I need to create a logic, that if two circles overlap, the one with smaller radius will dissapear, so:

1. how to keep the circle size the same, regardless of the zoom
2. how to create a logic in python to cancel the smaller overlapping circle?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313882/scatterplot-with-different-size-marker-and-color-from-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scatterplot with different size, marker, and color from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313882/scatterplot-with-different-size-marker-and-color-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Asmus i Just updated the question, see my notes below the code. would you be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: I think [Scale matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.scatter markersize by x-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172928/scale-matplotlib-pyplot-axes-scatter-markersize-by-x-scale/48174228#48174228) is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure which PCA parameter you want to be reflected in the circle size, but: either you want to

- use a scatter plot (i.e. `ax.scatter()`) whose `size=` is reflecting your chosen PCA parameter; this size will (and **should not**) rescale when you rescale the figure; it is also **not given** in (x,y)-units
- use multiple `plt.Circle((x,y), radius=radius, **kwargs)` patches, whose radii are given in (x,y)-units; the point overlap is then *consistent* on rescale, but this will likely cause deformed points

The following animation will emphasise the issue at hand:
[image: Rescaling different point plots]

I suppose you want the `plt.Circle`-based solution, as it keeps the distance *static*, and then you need to "manually" calculate beforehand whether two points overlap and delete them "manually". You should be able to do this automatically via a comparison between point size (i.e. `radius`, your PCA parameter) and the euclidian distance between your data points (i.e. `np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`).

To use Circles, you could e.g. define a shorthand function:

```
def my_circle_scatter(ax, x_array, y_array, radius=0.5, **kwargs):
    for x, y in zip(x_array, y_array):
        circle = plt.Circle((x,y), radius=radius, **kwargs)
        ax.add_patch(circle)
    return True
```

and then call it with optional parameters (i.e. the x- and y-coordinates, colors, and so on):

```
my_circle_scatter(ax, xs, ys, radius=0.2, alpha=.5, color='b')
```

Where I've used `fig,ax=plt.subplots()` to create the figure and subplot individually.

Comment: the radius is not related to PCA, or x,y but independent variable. with multiple `plt.Circle((x,y), radius=radius, **kwargs)` does it need to be in a loop? sorry what is **kwargs stands for?

Comment: @JayQadan `**kwargs` is a placeholder for any additional **k**ey**w**ord **arg**ument**s** you might pass, e.g. `color="r"`. I've updated my answer to include an example of `Circle()`

Comment: If you have many circles, you might want to consider using a [circle collection](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.CircleCollection)